# I was accidentally convert Java file to Kotlin file in Android Studio. How to convert back?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was accidentally convert Java file to Kotlin file in Android Studio.

I'm try to *Tools >> Kotlin >> Show Kotlin Bytecode >> Decompile*, but I can't click on the button, see below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to convert Kotlin to Java. When you accidentally converted it you have to press Ctrl + Z. ;)

Now if you have git to roll your changes back.

Answer (score 0):

As i see the kotlin file is not destroyed, but the "Decompile Java file" is added  on the right side of tabs. So there is no problem in loosing your code data.

[image]

Hope i understand your problem right.